# Ramda filter null prop

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have array of event objects, looks like:

```
{
    date: "2015-06-03T19:29:01.000Z",
    description: "Test",
    talks: [{
        author: "Nick",
        tags: ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
    }]
}
```

I want to take only tags from this object, so I use Ramda like this:

```
let eventTags = pipe(prop('talks'), map(prop('tags')), flatten, uniq)
... 
eventTags(event); //and call function on event object
```

But there is cases when event object looks like this:

```
{
    date: "2015-06-03T19:29:01.000Z",
    description: "Test",
    talks: [{
        author: "Nick",
        tags: null
    }]
}
```

So I got `[null]` in my `eventTags` array, but I want to get an empty array instead. So how can I filter null?

Comment: No need to use Ramda, just do `event.talks.tags || []`.

Comment: My mistake - talks is array of objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could utilise [`R.defaultTo([])`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#defaultTo) here to create a function that returns an empty array if null or undefined values are received, otherwise passing the value through unmodified.

```
const eventTags = pipe(
  prop('talks'),
  map(pipe(prop('tags'), defaultTo([]))),
  flatten,
  uniq
)
```

Comment: Please @MadMax mark the answer as accepted so that it does appear in unanswered questions ...

Answer (score 2):

I would advocate for a solution that could access `tags` using lenses and treat `undefined` as `Maybe Nothing` using both *Ramda*  and [*Sanctuary*](https://sanctuary.js.org/)

```
const x = [{
  date: "2015-06-03T19:29:01.000Z",
  description: "Test",
  talks: [{
    author: "Nick",
    tags: ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
  }]
}, {
  date: "2015-06-03T19:29:01.000Z",
  description: "Test",
  talks: [{
    author: "Nick",
    tags: null
  }]
}]

const viewTalks = S.compose ( S.toMaybe ) ( 
  R.view ( R.lensProp( 'talks' ) ) 
)

const viewTags = S.compose ( S.toMaybe ) ( 
  R.view ( R.lensProp ( 'tags' ) ) 
)

const allTalkTags = S.map ( S.pipe ( [
  S.map ( viewTags ),
  S.justs,
  R.unnest
] ) )

const allTalksTags = S.pipe( [
  S.map ( S.pipe( [
    viewTalks,
    allTalkTags
  ] ) ),
  S.justs,
  R.unnest,
  R.uniq
] )

// outputs: ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
allTalksTags ( x )
```

[Click to run a working sample](http://davidchase.github.io/ramtuary/#?code=const%20x%20%3D%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20date%3A%20%222015-06-03T19%3A29%3A01.000Z%22%2C%0A%20%20description%3A%20%22Test%22%2C%0A%20%20talks%3A%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20author%3A%20%22Nick%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20tags%3A%20%5B%22tag1%22%2C%20%22tag2%22%2C%20%22tag3%22%5D%0A%20%20%7D%5D%0A%7D%2C%20%7B%0A%20%20date%3A%20%222015-06-03T19%3A29%3A01.000Z%22%2C%0A%20%20description%3A%20%22Test%22%2C%0A%20%20talks%3A%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20author%3A%20%22Nick%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20tags%3A%20null%0A%20%20%7D%5D%0A%7D%5D%0A%0Aconst%20viewTalks%20%3D%20S.compose%20%28%20S.toMaybe%20%29%20%28%20%0A%20%20R.view%20%28%20R.lensProp%28%20%27talks%27%20%29%20%29%20%0A%29%0A%0Aconst%20viewTags%20%3D%20S.compose%20%28%20S.toMaybe%20%29%20%28%20%0A%20%20R.view%20%28%20R.lensProp%20%28%20%27tags%27%20%29%20%29%20%0A%29%0A%0Aconst%20allTalkTags%20%3D%20S.map%20%28%20S.pipe%20%28%20%5B%0A%20%20S.map%20%28%20viewTags%20%29%2C%0A%20%20S.justs%2C%0A%20%20R.unnest%0A%5D%20%29%20%29%0A%0Aconst%20allTalksTags%20%3D%20S.pipe%28%20%5B%0A%20%20S.map%20%28%20S.pipe%28%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20viewTalks%2C%0A%20%20%20%20allTalkTags%0A%20%20%5D%20%29%20%29%2C%0A%20%20S.justs%2C%0A%20%20R.flatten%2C%0A%20%20R.uniq%0A%5D%20%29%0A%0A%0AallTalksTags%20%28%20x%20%29)

Answer (score 1):

With Matías Fidemraizer help I changed my `eventTags` function to this:

```
const viewTags = talk => !!talk.tags ? talk.tags : [];

export let eventTags = pipe(prop('talks'), map(viewTags), flatten, uniq)
```

Comment: Check that I've refactored it just now because you turned `talks` into an array. Now my code covers this new requirement ;)

Comment: I see that you cover that `tags` may be `undefined` providing an empty array. Clearly it's simpler than using `Maybe` :D

Comment: Why not simplify using str's comment above, `viewTags = talk => talk.tags || []` ?